# How to send email with attachment using PHP?

Tags: php, email, email-attachments

I am using following code for sending email with attachment but the proper file is not getting attach with mail.

```
$UnidID = $_COOKIE['UniqueID'];
$guid = $_COOKIE['guid'];
$target_path = "userdata/".$UniqueID."/".$iGuid."/Outputs";
$fname = getpathmail($UnidID,$guid);
$target_path = $target_path.$filname;

$fileatt_type = "application/fbf"; // File Type
$fileatt_name = $fname; 
$data = $target_path;
$email_from = "EHPAdmin@fugro.in"; 
$email_subject = "EHP/PPP process";
$email_message = "Processed result for EHP/PPP processing";

$email_to = $_GET['Email'] ; 

$headers = "From: ".$email_from;

$semi_rand = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
"Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
" boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

$email_message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
"--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
$email_message .= "\n\n";

$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

$email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" .
" name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
$data .= "\n\n" .
"--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

$ok = @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

Comment: Have you or can you try using a class like [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/files/phpmailer%20for%20php5_6/)?

Comment: You can find a complete and working function here:
http://www.barattalo.it/2010/01/10/sending-emails-with-attachment-and-html-with-php/

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest to use a library for sending eMails as it will handle all the header related stuff. Have a look at [Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.attachments.html). Sending attachments is as easy as

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail();

$at = $mail->createAttachment($myImage);
$at->type        = 'image/gif';
$at->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_INLINE;
$at->encoding    = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_8BIT;
$at->filename    = 'test.gif';

$mail->send();
```

Comment: Yes, use the mailer class that your framework provides. No need to reinvent the wheel and add more code that needs to maintained.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put all of your multipart message into `$email_message`:

```
$semi_rand = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

$headers = "From: ".$email_from;
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
"Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
" boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

$email_message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
"--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
"--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" .
" name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
chunk_split(base64_encode($data)) .
"--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you missed this in your code

```
 ...

 $file = fopen($data,'rb');
 //saves content in $data itself
 $data = fread($file,filesize($data));
 fclose($file); 

 ...
```

should work havn't executed myself.
give it a try

Answer (score -1):

You should give your attachment file as:

```
"Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='/path/to/the/file/filename'";
```

Comment: It says *filename* and not *filepath*.

Comment: the property name is filename but you need to specify the complete path to the file otherwise how will know where to pick up the attached file.