# send email with attachment using php

Tags: php, email, attachment

I used this code to send email with attachment using php, but there is something error in the attachment since I receive an email and the attachment appears in the content. before I use the same code and it worked successfully. why???

```
<?php
// sending email with attachments

    function sendEmail($to,$from,$file,$ext){

      $to = "admin@fuwant.com";
     $from = "noor@fuwant.com";
      $subject = "Translation Request";

  $random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));

  $headers = "From: sahar@fuwant.com\r\nReply-To: admin@fuwant.com";

  $headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";

  $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents("Test.doc")));

  $output = "
        --PHP-mixed-$random_hash;
        Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary='PHP-alt-$random_hash'
        --PHP-alt-$random_hash
        Content-Type: text/plain; charset='iso-8859-1'
        Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

        Hello World!
        This is the simple text version of the email message.

        --PHP-alt-$random_hash
        Content-Type: text/html; charset='iso-8859-1'
        Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

        <h2>Hello World!</h2>
        <p>This is the <b>HTML</b> version of the email message.</p>

        --PHP-alt-$random_hash--

        --PHP-mixed-$random_hash
        Content-Type: application/doc; name=Test.doc
        Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
        Content-Disposition: attachment

        $attachment
        --PHP-mixed-$random_hash--";
      $send =  @mail($to, $subject, $output, $headers);
  return $send;
  }
?>
```

please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send email with attachment using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027069/how-to-send-email-with-attachment-using-php)

Comment: Your code is not worth fixing. It's btw the indentation that breaks the MIME markup.

Answer (score 6):

for what reason no use [phpmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)? example for an attachment:

```
function mandaMail ($nombredest, $maildest, $asunto, $cuerpo) {
require_once("mailer/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->IsSMTP();

try {
    $mail->Host = "xxxx"; $mail->Port = 25; // smtp server
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = "xxxx"; // smtp username
    $mail->Password = "xxxx"; // smtp pass
    $mail->AddReplyTo("xxxx", "xxxx"); // email & name
    $mail->SetFrom("xxxx", "xxxx"); // similar to up value

    $mail->AddAddress($maildest, $nombredest);
    $mail->Subject = $asunto;
    $mail->MsgHTML(file_get_contents($cuerpo));

    $mail->AddAttachment("xxxx", "xxxx"); // attachments directory, attachment name (ie: dir/blah.jpg, blah.jpg)
    $mail->Send();

} catch (phpmailerException $e) { echo $e->errorMessage();
} catch (Exception $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either do it the way [this](http://www.geekology.co.za/blog/2009/06/sending-emails-with-attachments-using-php-mail-function/) tutorial describes, or you can use one of the [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.php) modules to send an email with an attachment the way [this](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.example.php) tutorial describes.

Using PEAR is probably a better option as it's easier to do. The only caveat is that PEAR isn't available on all hosts.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using this :

```
function attachfile($file, $type = "application/octetstream")  {
    if(!($fd = fopen($file, "r"))) {
      $this->errstr = "Error opening $file for reading.";
      return 0;
    }
    $_buf = fread($fd, filesize($file));
    fclose($fd);

    $fname = $file;
    for($x = strlen($file); $x > 0; $x--)
      if($file[$x] == "/")
        $fname = substr($file, $x, strlen($file) - $x);

    // Convert to base64 becuase mail attachments are not binary safe.
    $_buf = chunk_split(base64_encode($_buf));

    $this->attachments[$file] = "\n--" . $this->boundary . "\n";
    $this->attachments[$file] .= "Content-Type: $type; name=\"$fname\"\n";
    $this->attachments[$file] .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
    $this->attachments[$file] .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; " .
                                     "filename=\"$fname\"\n\n";
    $this->attachments[$file] .= $_buf;

    return 1;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code wont be work, because email doesnt support *whitespaces*.

> ```
>   $output = "
>        --PHP-mixed-$random_hash;
>        Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary='PHP-alt-$random_hash'
>        --PHP-alt-$random_hash
>        Content-Type: text/plain; charset='iso-8859-1'
>        Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
> ```

You must use without *whitespaces*

> ```
>  $output = "
>  --PHP-mixed-$random_hash;
>  Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary='PHP-alt-$random_hash'
>  --PHP-alt-$random_hash
>  Content-Type: text/plain; charset='iso-8859-1'
>  Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this and ( with out using **PHPMailer** ), Hope this is helpful to you.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="">
    <label>Your Name <input type="text" name="sender_name" /> </label> <br>
    <label>Your Email <input type="email" name="sender_email" /> </label> <br>
    <label>Subject <input type="text" name="subject" /> </label> <br>
    <label>Message <textarea name="message"></textarea> </label> <br>
    <label>Attachment <input type="file" name="my_file" /></label><br>
    <label><input type="submit" name="button" value="Submit" /></label>
</form>

<?php 
echo "<pre>";print_r($_REQUEST);echo "</pre>"; //comment this line
echo "<pre>";print_r($_FILES);echo "</pre>"; //comment this line
if($_POST && isset($_FILES['my_file']))
{

    $from_email         = 'noreply@your_domain.com'; //from mail, it is mandatory with some hosts
    $recipient_email    = 'your-emailid@gmail.com'; //recipient email (most cases it is your personal email)

    //Capture POST data from HTML form and Sanitize them, 
    $sender_name    = filter_var($_POST["sender_name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //sender name
    $reply_to_email = filter_var($_POST["sender_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //sender email used in "reply-to" header
    $subject        = filter_var($_POST["subject"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //get subject from HTML form
    //$message        = filter_var($_POST["message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //message
    $message        = "Name : ".$sender_name."\nMessage : ".$_POST["message"]; //message

    //Get uploaded file data
    $file_tmp_name    = $_FILES['my_file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_name        = $_FILES['my_file']['name'];
    $file_size        = $_FILES['my_file']['size'];
    $file_type        = $_FILES['my_file']['type'];
    $file_error       = $_FILES['my_file']['error'];

    if($file_error > 0)
    {
        die('Upload error or No files uploaded');
    }
    //read from the uploaded file & base64_encode content for the mail
    $handle = fopen($file_tmp_name, "r");
    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

        $boundary = md5("sanwebe");
        //headers
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
        $headers .= "From:".$from_email."\r\n"; 
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$reply_to_email."" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n"; 

        //body plain text 
        $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"; 
        $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($message)); 

        //attachment file
        $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
        $body .="Content-Type: $file_type; name=".$file_name."\r\n";
        $body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file_name."\r\n";
        $body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
        $body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n"; 
        $body .= $encoded_content; 
    $sentMail = @mail($recipient_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
    if($sentMail) //output success or failure messages
    {       
        die('Thank you for your email');
    }else{
        die('Could not send mail!');  
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It also works very well in that way:

```
$to = 'bla@test.de'; 
 $from = 'blub@test.de'; 
$fromName = 'Me'; 


$subject = 'Hello';  


$file = "D:/xxxxxxx/kanal_uebersicht.pdf"; 


$htmlContent= "Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren, \r\n";
 $htmlContent.= "blabla. \r\n";
$htmlContent.= "Mit freundlichen Grüßen, \r\n";
$htmlContent.= "blabla. \r\n";



$headers = "From: $fromName"." <".$from.">"; 


$semi_rand = md5(time());  
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";  

$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 


$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n" . 
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $htmlContent . "\n\n";  


if(!empty($file) > 0){ 
    if(is_file($file)){ 
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n"; 
        $fp =    @fopen($file,"rb"); 
        $data =  @fread($fp,filesize($file)); 

        @fclose($fp); 
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data)); 
        $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".basename($file)."\"\n" .  
        "Content-Description: ".basename($file)."\n" . 
        "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"".basename($file)."\"; size=".filesize($file).";\n" .  
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n"; 
    } 
} 
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--"; 
$returnpath = "-f" . $from; 


$mail = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $returnpath);
```