# Why is this php mailer script fort HTML & attachments not working?

Tags: php, html, email, sendmail, email-attachments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to send email with attachment using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027069/how-to-send-email-with-attachment-using-php)
>   [PHP mail() attachment problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275070/php-mail-attachment-problems)

I'm trying to implement this script:
[Send PHP HTML mail with attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519588/send-php-html-mail-with-attachments)

The only thing I've modified in the script was the send-to address and the file.  I'm trying to attach an `.mp3` file instead of a `.zip` file - maybe this is the reason I'm getting unexpected results?

The `.mp3` file is only 31kb

But when I receive the email, there is no attachment and no HTML formatting in the message.

The email message contains:

```
--PHP-mixed-a80d597fc7c02e67ff5be867c7a48bab
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-a80d597fc7c02e67ff5be867c7a48bab"

--PHP-alt-a80d597fc7c02e67ff5be867c7a48bab
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hello World!!!
This is simple text email message.

--PHP-alt-a80d597fc7c02e67ff5be867c7a48bab
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<h2>Hello World!</h2>
<p>This is something with <b>HTML</b> formatting.</p>

--PHP-alt-a80d597fc7c02e67ff5be867c7a48bab--

--PHP-mixed-a80d597fc7c02e67ff5be867c7a48bab
Content-Type: application/zip; name="attachment.zip"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment

SUQzAwAAAAABIVRQRTEAAAAfAAAB//5DAGgAZQBlAHMAZQBDA.....
```

Comment: Why don't you use something like SwiftMailer or PHPMailer if you're overwhelmed with MIME construction?

Comment: I won't answer your question because it's really painful to send an html email using PHP from scratch when there is Swiftmailer for example ..

Comment: found my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275070/php-mail-attachment-problems

Comment: Found my solution here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275070/php-mail-attachment-problems

Answer (score 0):

I am looking at this line in your mail:

Content-Type: application/zip; name="attachment.zip"

You are attaching a mp3 file, so your content type should be audio/mpeg3 and the filename should be according to whatever you are sending.

Content-Type: audio/mpeg3; name="somefile.mp3"

Also - be careful of the 64 bit encoding. You have to encode the mp3 in order to mail it, because you will again get unexpected results if you don't.